# Sqlite SELECT syntax

Tags: sql, sqlite

A common form of SQL SELECT names fetched records as in

```
SELECT * from employee e1 ...
```

where the `e1` is added as the name of the record, to be further referred to in the body of the query.

Where exactly in the syntax definition for SELECT is a record name provided for? Sqlite does indeed support this syntax, but I've been looking at the syntax diagram and I can't see any mention of such an option:

https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Comment: e1 is a _table alias_.

Comment: Look in the definition of "table-or-subquery".

Comment: @jarlh exactly, and it appears in the diagram if op expands the `table-or-subquery` section

Answer (score 1):

Look at the schema for [`table-or-subquery`](https://sqlite.org/syntax/table-or-subquery.html) after the table name you can add an optional `table-alias` with an optional `AS` to clarify the use of an alias. `e1` in your example is a `table-alias`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from employee as e1;
```

e1 is a table alias.

But if you write your syntax like this

```
SELECT e1 from employee;
```

You are selecting the data in column `e1` from the table `employee`.